# Replacing certain parts of Array in different folders via Pythion

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, python-2.7

## My code does the replacement for the entire file. Whereas I want only certain replacements.

## Below is the file I'm trying to replace. I just want to change some words in "sheetname" : "Main"

```
 [  
  {
   "sheetname": "Main",
   "emp_details": [
        [
            "スバム",
            "ksing.shubh@gmail.com",
            "marble",
            "intern"
        ],
        [
            "Gaurav",
            "gaurav.singh@cobol.in",
            "snacks",
            "デボロッパ"
        ],
        [
            "ニキル",
            "nikhil@geeksforgeeks.org",
            "tennis",
            "Full Time"
        ]
       ]
     },
     {
    "sheetname": "Next",
    "emp_details": [
            [
                "スバム",
                "ksing.shubh@gmail.com",
                "fabrics",
                "intern"
            ],
            [
                "Gaurav",
                "gaurav.singh@cobol.in",
                "xenom",
                "デボロッパ"
            ],
            [
                "ニキル",
                "nikhil@geeksforgeeks.org",
                "hiltop",
                "Full Time"
            ]
          ]
         }
        ,{
        "sheetname": "Last",
        "emp_details": [
                [
                    "スバム",
                    "ksing.shubh@gmail.com",
                    "trend",
                    "intern"
                ],
                [
                    "Gaurav",
                    "gaurav.singh@cobol.in",
                    "souvenir",
                    "デボロッパ"
                ],
                [
                    "ニキル",
                    "nikhil@geeksforgeeks.org",
                    "urban",
                    "Full Time"
                ]
            ]
        }
 ]
```

## What I'm trying to do is to replace certain words in the "Main" "sheet" i.e. sheetname = Main;

## Thanks in advance. Any help would be great!

## Below is my code:

```
import os, re

directory = os.listdir('/Users/Unicorn/Desktop/for all/change')
os.chdir('/Users/Unicorn/Desktop/for all/change')

for file in directory:
    open_file = open(file,'r', encoding='utf-8')
    read_file = open_file.read()
    #　changing value
    regex = re.compile('Gaurav')
    #　change value
    read_file = regex.sub('Singh', read_file)
    write_file = open(file,'w', encoding='utf-8')
    write_file.write(read_file)
```

Comment: which data you need to replace?

Comment: for e.g. Gaurav of "Main" to Singh.

Comment: you mean  "Gaurav" in "sheetname": "Main" into "Singh"?

Comment: ya, it should be changed in only "sheetname": "Main".

Comment: Hi, using only bold fonts or headers is a bit like shouting. Using `#` for headers in order to better show the structure of your post is fine, but using them consistently throughout all the post could be seen as not polite. No need to fix it here, but please refrain for your next post.

Comment: There are 2 different ways to solve the problem. If the text format is fixed and matters (order of fields and presence of new lines), a textual approach should be used. Else, is you want to change *words* in a list of lists, you'd better parse the file with the json module, and only process the appropriate dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for your kind suggestion, I'll keep that in mind the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is a json data, if you save it in a file, it can be loaded with json module and simply iterate then add your condition

```
import json
import os
import sys

directory = os.listdir('/Users/Unicorn/Desktop/for all/change')
os.chdir('/Users/Unicorn/Desktop/for all/change')

for file in directory:
    open_file = open(file,'r', encoding='utf-8')
    read_file = open_file.read()
    open_file.close()
    # loads json file so it can be treated just like dictionary/list object in python
    data_json = json.loads(read_file)

    # iterate sheet item in data
    for sheet in data_json:
        # this is where you put your condition for sheetname == "Main"
        if sheet['sheetname'] == 'Main':
            # iterate over emp_detail because it is a list
            for emp_detail in sheet['emp_details']:
                # this is my simple method to replace item on a list
                if 'Gaurav' in emp_detail:
                    emp_detail[emp_detail.index('Gaurav')] = 'Singh'
    data_final = json.dumps(data_json)
    open_file = open(file,'w', encoding='utf-8')
    open_file.write(data_final)
    open_file.close()
```

Comment: Actually it's working and not working. I mean it works for the condition very well but the Japanese characters become some kinda unicode. And also I want to get the design for the output file. 
But thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Naming you data from file as `data`:

```
 data = [  
  {
   "sheetname": "Main",
   "emp_details": [
        [
            "スバム",
            "ksing.shubh@gmail.com",
            "marble",
            "intern"
        ],
        [
            "Gaurav",
            "gaurav.singh@cobol.in",
            "snacks",
            "デボロッパ"
        ],
        [
            "ニキル",
            "nikhil@geeksforgeeks.org",
            "tennis",
            "Full Time"
        ]
       ]
     },
     {
    "sheetname": "Next",
    "emp_details": [
            [
                "スバム",
                "ksing.shubh@gmail.com",
                "fabrics",
                "intern"
            ],
            [
                "Gaurav",
                "gaurav.singh@cobol.in",
                "xenom",
                "デボロッパ"
            ],
            [
                "ニキル",
                "nikhil@geeksforgeeks.org",
                "hiltop",
                "Full Time"
            ]
          ]
         }
        ,{
        "sheetname": "Last",
        "emp_details": [
                [
                    "スバム",
                    "ksing.shubh@gmail.com",
                    "trend",
                    "intern"
                ],
                [
                    "Gaurav",
                    "gaurav.singh@cobol.in",
                    "souvenir",
                    "デボロッパ"
                ],
                [
                    "ニキル",
                    "nikhil@geeksforgeeks.org",
                    "urban",
                    "Full Time"
                ]
            ]
        }
 ]

import re

word_to_replace = 'Gaurav'
word_to_assign = 'Singh'

for dictionary in data:
    if dictionary.get('sheetname') == 'Main':
        list_data = dictionary.get('emp_details')
        new_data = []
        for item in list_data:
            if word_to_replace in item:
                new_item = []
                for word in item:
                    if word.lower().find(word_to_replace.lower()) == 0:
                        new_word = re.sub(word_to_replace, word_to_assign, word)
                        if new_word == word:
                            new_word = re.sub(word_to_replace.lower(), word_to_assign.lower(), word)
                        new_item.append(new_word)
                    else:
                        new_item.append(word)
                new_data.append(new_item)
            else:
                new_data.append(item)

        dictionary['emp_details'] = new_data
```

**Output**:

```
[{'sheetname': 'Main', 'emp_details': [['スバム', 'ksing.shubh@gmail.com', 'marble', 'intern'], ['Singh', 'singh.singh@cobol.in', 'snacks', 'デボロッパ'], ['ニキル', 'nikhil@geeksforgeeks.org', 'tennis', 'Full Time']]}, {'sheetname': 'Next', 'emp_details': [['スバム', 'ksing.shubh@gmail.com', 'fabrics', 'intern'], ['Gaurav', 'gaurav.singh@cobol.in', 'xenom', 'デボロッパ'], ['ニキル', 'nikhil@geeksforgeeks.org', 'hiltop', 'Full Time']]}, {'sheetname': 'Last', 'emp_details': [['スバム', 'ksing.shubh@gmail.com', 'trend', 'intern'], ['Gaurav', 'gaurav.singh@cobol.in', 'souvenir', 'デボロッパ'], ['ニキル', 'nikhil@geeksforgeeks.org', 'urban', 'Full Time']]}]
```

Comment: I don't know why but the code isn't working. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @Rubin you get some error? I have tested this on you listed data. `data` need to by a list of dictionary.

Comment: Can you plz add a full code, maybe its because I've mistaken somewhere.
Sorry for bothering!

Comment: @Rubin added assign list of dictionary to variable `data`

Comment: I did something like this.

     import json
     word_to_replace = 'Gaurav'
     new_word = 'Singh'
     with open('new.json', 'r',encoding='utf-8') as file:
       data = json.load(file)
     for dictionary in data:
         if dictionary.get('sheetname') == 'Main':
      ..............(copied the code).........      
      dictionary['emp_details'] = new_data
     with open('wow.json', 'w',encoding='utf-8') as file:
       json.dump(data, file, indent=4)

     The problem is that the japanese characters become /u... like that.

Comment: It worked @Zaraki. 
But I was unable to change the words in between. For e.g. I can't change "gaurav.singh@cobol.in" 's only singh = network.
Can you help me out with this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Rubin code updated. Now if email contains `word_to_replace` it will by replaced

Comment: I'm sorry to say but the problem isn't solved yet.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: @Rubin ... don't know what you need ... good luck with coding